# How to insert values into Mysql.js table in Node express project

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mysqljs

This is my use case.

1. First I insert data to the customer table.
2. Then I get the insertId for the customer.
3. Then I try to insert data into address table using that id.

```js
async function createCustomer(req, res, next) {
    const customer = {
        type: req.body.type,
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        email: req.body.email
    };
    
    const first_line = req.body.first_line

    console.log("Customer from front-end", customer);

    try {
        let query1 = "INSERT INTO customer_supplier SET ?";
        connection.query(query1, customer, (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error", error);
            } else {
                let userId = results.insertId;
                let query2 = "INSERT INTO address (id,first_line) VALUES ?";


                connection.query(query2, [userId, first_line], (error, results) => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log("error in address ==================================", error)

                    } else {
                        res.json({
                            results: results
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        });

      
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error from", error);
        res.json({
            error: error
        });
    }
}
```

But when I try to insert data into the address table,

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'36\' at line 1',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'INSERT INTO address (id,first_line) VALUES 36' }
```

Before put this question on stackoverflow I tried so many variations in my insert statement and nothing works for me.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: check the data type if id field in address table. I think it is integer in address table and you are getting string from results.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql is not written correct,you need to add `()` to wrap the value

```
let query2 = "INSERT INTO address (id,first_line) VALUES (?,?)";
```

Below is the grammar to use `INSERT INTO`

```
> INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) 
> VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

would you try this one

```
   let query2 = "INSERT INTO address (id,first_line) VALUES ('userId', 'first_line')"

connection.query(query2, (error, results)
```